# DEBUG = False / "Server Error (500)" - Django

Tags: python, django, debugging, server-error

I have a fully built Django python website and now I'm launching it into production. I'm trying to set DEBUG equal to False for production with limited success. I have been working on this problem on and off for about a week and here is what I've got.

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
```

This makes most pages work and I think the pages where it works are the HTML pages that are extended from another page that looks for the CSS files and images in the head tag or at least that is the only correlation I can see. Some pages properly show the contents and when there is an error it shows "Server Error (500)" or something along those lines. For other pages that don't work, they never display the proper contents and just automatically show "Server Error (500)" or something along those lines. When it does always give this error I get an error in my terminal that says

raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'style.css'

I do have a static CSS file called style.css that contributes to some of the HTML files but I see no problems with it and no differences between it and other CSS files I have that work. Im really stuck at this point and will take all the help I can get. Thanks!

P.S. I have already run "python manage.py collectstatic"

**UPDATE:**
here is additional code to help.

settings.py (full):

```
import django_heroku
from pathlib import Path
import os
from django_quill import quill

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
#BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BAS_DIR, 'media')
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%I:%M %p',]

#Media_URL = '/signup/front_page/sheets/'


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


#ADMIN_USERNAME = 'lhy'
#ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'pbkdf2_sha256$180000$nMNyyIvw0TgW$BWgVFXrb25VY7+QVURr4/QawrSTbHIksIYzoC3rWyRc='
#AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
 #   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 #   'config.backends.SettingsBackend',
#]


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': 'link image imagetools preview codesample contextmenu table code lists print save autosave fullscreen spellchecker textcolor',
    'toolbar1': 'fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent | table | link image | preview',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'inline': False,
    'statusbar': True,
    'width': 740,
    'height': 990,
}
#TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True

QUILL_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'theme': 'snow',
        'modules': {
            #'syntax': True,
            #'imageResize': True,
            'toolbar': [
                [
                    {'font': []},
                    {'header': []},
                    {'align': []},
                    'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote',
                    {'color': []},
                    {'size': []},
                    {'background': []},
                ],
                ['code-block', 'link'],
                ['clean'],
                ['link', 'image'],
            ],
        }
    }
}

CKEDITOR_THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (500, 500)

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'height': '1010',
        'width': '747',
        'skin': 'moono',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Save', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Table', 'SpecialChar']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor', 'ShowBlocks']},
            #{'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
            '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here

            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        # 'height': 291,
        # 'width': '100%',
        # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            # 'devtools',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath'
        ]),
    }
}

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
    'django_quill',
    'tinymce',
    'ckeditor',

    'boto3',

    #'django_extensions',

    'storages',
    #'django-storages',

    'django_filters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'inspect_list.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'inspect_list.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'SECRET'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'SECRET'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'SECRET'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Caracas'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

#MEDIA_URL = '/images/'
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/images/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '..','www','media')

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.CustomUser'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'front_page'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

The url.py file that contains the pages that automatically get a %)) error:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
from django.urls import include

from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Sheets.as_view(), name='sheets'),

    path('add_data_asbestos/', views.adddata_asbestos, name='create_asbestos'),
    path('add_data_defibrillators/', views.adddata_defibrillators, name='create_defibrillators'),
    path('add_data_firealarms_sprinklers/', views.adddata_firealarms_sprinklers, name='create_firealarms_sprinklers'),
    path('add_data_building/', views.adddata_building, name='create_building'),
    path('add_data_incident/', views.adddata_incident, name='create_incident'),
    path('add_data_extinguisher/', views.adddata_extinguisher, name='create_extinguisher'),
    path('add_data_call/', views.adddata_call, name='create_call'),

    path('add_data_asbestos-mobile/', views.adddata_asbestos_mobile, name='create_asbestos_mobile'),
    path('add_data_defibrillators-mobile/', views.adddata_defibrillators_mobile, name='create_defibrillators_mobile'),
    path('add_data_firealarms_sprinklers-mobile/', views.adddata_firealarms_sprinklers_mobile, name='create_firealarms_sprinklers_mobile'),
    path('add_data_building-mobile/', views.adddata_building_mobile, name='create_building_mobile'),
    path('add_data_incident-mobile/', views.adddata_incident_mobile, name='create_incident_mobile'),
    path('add_data_extinguisher-mobile/', views.adddata_extinguisher_mobile, name='create_extinguisher_mobile'),
    path('add_data_call-mobile/', views.adddata_call_mobile, name='create_call_mobile'),

    path('<int:pk>/update_data_asbestos/', views.UpdataData_Asbestos.as_view(), name='update_asbestos'),
    path('<int:pk>/update_data_defibrillators/', views.UpdataData_Defibrillators.as_view(), name='update_defibrillators'),
    path('<int:pk>/update_data_firealarms_sprinklers/', views.UpdataData_Firealarms_Sprinklers.as_view(), name='update_firealarms_sprinklers'),
    path('<int:pk>/update_data_building/', views.UpdataData_Building.as_view(), name='update_building'),
    path('<int:pk>/update_data_incident/', views.UpdataData_Incident.as_view(), name='update_incident'),
    path('<int:pk>/update_data_extinguisher/', views.UpdataData_Extinguisher.as_view(), name='update_extinguisher'),
    path('<int:pk>/update_data_call/', views.UpdataData_Call.as_view(), name='update_call'),

    path('list_data_asbestos/', views.ListData_Asbestos.as_view(), name='list_asbestos'),
    path('list_data_defibrillators/', views.ListData_Defibrillators.as_view(), name='list_defibrillators'),
    path('list_data_firealarms_sprinklers/', views.ListData_Firealarms_Sprinklers.as_view(), name='list_firealarms_sprinklers'),
    path('list_data_building/', views.ListData_Building.as_view(), name='list_building'),
    path('list_data_incident/', views.ListData_Incident.as_view(), name='list_incident'),
    path('list_data_extinguisher/', views.ListData_Extinguisher.as_view(), name='list_extinguisher'),
    path('list_data_call/', views.ListData_Call.as_view(), name='list_call'),

    path('<int:pk>/delete_data_asbestos/', views.DeleteData_Asbestos.as_view(), name='delete_asbestos'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete_data_defibrillators/', views.DeleteData_Defibrillators.as_view(), name='delete_defibrillators'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete_data_firealarms_sprinklers/', views.DeleteData_Firealarms_Sprinklers.as_view(), name='delete_firealarms_sprinklers'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete_data_building/', views.DeleteData_Building.as_view(), name='delete_building'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete_data_incident/', views.DeleteData_Incident.as_view(), name='delete_incident'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete_data_extinguisher/', views.DeleteData_Extinguisher.as_view(), name='delete_extinguisher'),
    path('<int:pk>/delete_data_call/', views.DeleteData_Call.as_view(), name='delete_call'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and...

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views
from django.urls import include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.docpostlistview, name='doc-post-list'),

    path('Template1/', views.Template1.as_view(), name='template1'),
    path('Example/', views.Example.as_view(), name='example'),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

It's mainly '' for the first and second URL files that automatically give 500 errors when debug=false no matter what.

**UPDATE2:**

```
import django_heroku
from pathlib import Path
import os
from django_quill import quill

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
#BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BAS_DIR, 'media')
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%I:%M %p',]

#Media_URL = '/signup/front_page/sheets/'


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'SECRET'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


#ADMIN_USERNAME = 'SECRET'
#ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'SECRET'
#AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
 #   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 #   'config.backends.SettingsBackend',
#]


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'


TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': 'link image imagetools preview codesample contextmenu table code lists print save autosave fullscreen spellchecker textcolor',
    'toolbar1': 'fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | bold italic underline | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist | outdent indent | table | link image | preview',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'inline': False,
    'statusbar': True,
    'width': 740,
    'height': 990,
}
#TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = True

QUILL_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'theme': 'snow',
        'modules': {
            #'syntax': True,
            #'imageResize': True,
            'toolbar': [
                [
                    {'font': []},
                    {'header': []},
                    {'align': []},
                    'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote',
                    {'color': []},
                    {'size': []},
                    {'background': []},
                ],
                ['code-block', 'link'],
                ['clean'],
                ['link', 'image'],
            ],
        }
    }
}

CKEDITOR_THUMBNAIL_SIZE = (500, 500)

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'height': '1010',
        'width': '747',
        'skin': 'moono',
        'toolbar_Basic': [
            ['Source', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic']
        ],
        'toolbar_YourCustomToolbarConfig': [
            {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Save', 'Print', '-', 'Templates']},
            {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Cut', 'Copy', '-', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
            {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'basicstyles',
             'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript']},
            {'name': 'paragraph',
             'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', '-', 'Outdent', 'Indent', '-',
                       'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight', 'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl']},
            {'name': 'insert',
             'items': ['Image', 'Table', 'SpecialChar']},
            '/',
            {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']},
            {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor', 'ShowBlocks']},
            #{'name': 'about', 'items': ['About']},
            '/',  # put this to force next toolbar on new line
            {'name': 'yourcustomtools', 'items': [
                # put the name of your editor.ui.addButton here

            ]},
        ],
        'toolbar': 'YourCustomToolbarConfig',  # put selected toolbar config here
        # 'toolbarGroups': [{ 'name': 'document', 'groups': [ 'mode', 'document', 'doctools' ] }],
        # 'height': 291,
        # 'width': '100%',
        # 'filebrowserWindowHeight': 725,
        # 'filebrowserWindowWidth': 940,
        # 'toolbarCanCollapse': True,
        # 'mathJaxLib': '//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.2-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        'tabSpaces': 4,
        'extraPlugins': ','.join([
            'uploadimage', # the upload image feature
            # your extra plugins here
            'div',
            'autolink',
            'autoembed',
            'embedsemantic',
            # 'devtools',
            'widget',
            'lineutils',
            'clipboard',
            'dialog',
            'dialogui',
            'elementspath'
        ]),
    }
}

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
    'django_quill',
    'tinymce',
    'ckeditor',

    'boto3',

    #'django_extensions',

    'storages',
    #'django-storages',

    'django_filters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'inspect_list.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'inspect_list.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'SECRET'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'SECRET'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'SECRET'

AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Caracas'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

USE_S3 = os.getenv('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'

if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # s3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.CustomUser'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'front_page'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Comment: Have you a `STATICFILES_STORAGE` variable defined in your `settings.py` file ? And on which platform do you deploy your production app ? VPS or Heroku like services ?

Comment: STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'  in the case your forget to define. Run `collectstatic` after.

Comment: @Rvector I didn't have that variable before but I added it to settings.py. I then ran collectstatic again but I'm still encountering the same problems and the characteristics of the problem have not changed. I'm deploying off of Heroku if that changes anything. Thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Update the post with the total `settings.py` file and the project level `urls.py` file too.

Comment: @Rvector I added the necessary updates under the heading "UPDATES:".  Hope it helps

Comment: We need another approach to solve this problem. Turn `DEBUG` to `True` ; `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')` and run `./manage.py collectstatic`. Go to the console and see if some errors happen.

Comment: @Rvector I have followed the instructions and have gotten no errors in the console nor in the actual website.

Comment: @Rvector I continued to try and still have no luck. Any advice.

Comment: Are you really using `Amazon s3` for static and media files storage ? If no comment the line about `s3` in the config. If yes, the `s3` configs are not corrects.  I add an answer in the case you want use `s3`

Comment: I am not currently using amazon s3 for image storage for another portion of my website but not for static. I have followed all the instructions you have and thank you so much for them. I am updating my original post with "UPDATE2:" it will be my new settings.py file. My files are still being hosted locally and when I delete the files locally and add them to my bucket it doesn't show them. Even when I inspect the page it doesn't show them looking for the statics in S3. Do they have to be in a specific folder name in S3? Ive been at it for a few days more and still no luck. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Rvector I replaces STATICFILES_STORAGE with STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage' but still no luck after a few more hours of work.

Answer (score 1):

**This is how you can do if you want configure AWS for serving static files in production an let Django development server handle this on development mode**

1. **Install `boto3` and `django-storages`**
   `pip install boto3 django-storages`
2. **Add `STORAGES` to installed apps in Django project settings**

   INSTALLED_APP =
   [
   # ...,
   'storages',
   # ...
   ]
3. **Configure the static files variables with s3**

Replace:

```
STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
```

By :

```
USE_S3 = os.getenv('USE_S3') == 'TRUE'

if USE_S3:
    # aws settings
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.getenv('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
    AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400'}
    # s3 static settings
    AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{AWS_LOCATION}/'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
else:
    STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)

MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
```

**NB :** The `USE_S3` environment variable is used to turn the `s3` storage on (set to `TRUE`) and off(not set or set to `FALSE`).